# Append new value after certain character in a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert the opacity value in the HEX color value. I have the following HEX color value. I want to append ***AA*** value after the ***#***. I am using the following code and i am getting the error:
***Uncaught TypeError: buttonColor.splice is not a function***

```
var opactiyVal = [26, 40, 66 , 50];
var buttonColor = '#ffff';
var colorOptions = [];
while (i < 5){
  colorOptions[i] = buttonColor.splice(1, 0,opactiyVal[i]);
  i++;
  console.log(colorOptions[i]);
}
```

Comment: `splice` works on arrays, not strings

Comment: thanks for that. can you please suggest the appropriate method i can use in this scenario ?

Comment: @Victor See the String Documentation for a start - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: You'll want to tell us what your inputs and expected outputs are. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Please provide a sample *input* and *output*. The provided code doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is just for arrays. If you turn the string to an array using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), then back again using [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), it should work. Try this:

```
while (i<5){
  let buttonColorArr = buttonColor.split("");
  colorOptions[i] = buttonColorArr.splice(1, 0,opactiyVal[i]);
  colorOptions[i] = colorOptions[i].join("");
  i++;
  console.log(colorOptions[i]);
}
```

I'd also recommend changing the while loop to a [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop. The latter is more robust in that it is less likely to result in an infinite loop if the code doesn't run quite as expected.

Comment: thanks @223seneca. it worked. do you recommend any other approach to achieve the goal? My major goal is add the opacity to the exiting HEX color .

Comment: This approach seem fine to me. I'd do something similar. Since the solution worked, can you accept it?